# Loss of quality when converting from IplImage to UIImage

Tags: opencv, uiimage, iplimage

I'm using the OpenCV library in my app and I want to the use the final result as a UIImage.
I use this code to convert between IplImage to UIImage:

```
CGColorSpaceRef colorSpace = CGColorSpaceCreateDeviceRGB();
NSData * data = [[NSData alloc] initWithBytes:image->imageData length:image->imageSize];
CGDataProviderRef provider = CGDataProviderCreateWithCFData((__bridge CFDataRef)data);
CGImageRef imageRef = CGImageCreate(image->width, image->height,
                                    image->depth, image->depth * image->nChannels, image->widthStep,
                                    colorSpace, kCGImageAlphaPremultipliedLast|kCGBitmapByteOrderDefault,
                                    provider, NULL, false, kCGRenderingIntentDefault);
UIImage *ret = [[UIImage alloc] initWithCGImage:imageRef];
CGImageRelease(imageRef);
CGDataProviderRelease(provider);
CGColorSpaceRelease(colorSpace);
```

My problem is that after the conversion the quality of the original image decreases and the image is kind of blurry.

What is wrong with my code?

Comment: Probably Apple malware stuff

Comment: Ha? Please explain...